# My first bit of coding, but i have no clue if it's right

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft

My friend showed me her coding for a Minecraft plugin where you can spawn 10 creepers around a player. It wasn't working in-game. So, I decided to look at some tutorials for java coding and attempt it myself, however, I have no clue if it's right. Would someone be able to look it over and tell me I got at least some of it right? thank you!

```java
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.entity.EntityType;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin; 
public final class TestPlugin extends JavaPlugin 
{   
     @Override
        public void onEnable() {
            getLogger().info("onEnable has been invoked!");
        }
        
        @Override
        public void onDisable() {
            getLogger().info("onDisable has been invoked!");
        }

@Override
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
    for(int = 0; i < 10; i++) {
}
    if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("creepspawn")) { 
        return true;
    } else if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("creepspawn2")) {
        if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
            sender.sendMessage("This command can only run by player.");
        } else {
            Player player = (Player) sender;
            
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
    
    case "creepspawn";
        Location spawnLoc = player.getLocation(2,0,0);
        World world = player.getWorld();
        
        Creeper creeper = (Creeper) world.spawnenentity(spawnloc, EntityType.CREEPER); 
        
        return true; 
}
```

Comment: After `return false:` the code from `case` to `return true:` must be removed ("unreachable code" error).

Comment: Also, you never closed the string for ‘onDisable has been invoked’. Hence why it’s mostly highlighted green (on mine at least) in the question.

Comment: @JoopEggen how and where would i be able to put in what i need the command to do?

Comment: `Location ... CREEPER):` was maybe intended to be placed before the first `return true;`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to distinghuish between the commands. The code starts with using `if` statements, and then has code using a `case`. Maybe a teacher added that code snippet. Below I changed all to `switch` which indeed is a bit simpler.

```
@Override
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {

    switch (cmd.getName().toLowerCase()) {
    case "creepspawn":
        Location spawnLoc = player.getLocation(2,0,0);
        World world = player.getWorld();
    
        Creeper creeper = (Creeper) world.spawnenentity(spawnloc, 
            EntityType.CREEPER); 
        return true;
    case "creepspawn2":
        if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
            sender.sendMessage("This command can only run by player.");
        } else {
            Player player = (Player) sender;
        
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The code is far from complete. But now you can yourself have a go at it.